# AMP with javascript

Tags: javascript

I've gone through AMP-script documentation and I've been stuck for 1 day, trying to make this work.

I need to import JS remotely and use it in local. This is how I use it without AMP.

```
<!-- html -->
<span id="progressive_span">UPDATING</span>

<!-- js -->
<script src="https://tickers.ABC.com/hello.js"></script>
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (event) {
        var ticker = new Ticker({ info: 2 });
                    ticker.attachToTextBox('progressive_span');
                    ticker.SetCurrencySign('IDR ');
                    ticker.tick();
    });
</script>
```

import amp-script component.

```
<!doctype html>
<html ⚡>
<head>
  ...
  <script async custom-element="amp-script" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-script-0.1.js"></script>
  <meta name="amp-script-src" content="sha384-8T8pKdbkYmCLBlmEg0YkG9znnZfyf0AgBGSvAkuh5yeiOhD9K1PSaHOO3TjlrEkt"/>
<body>
```

Wrap the html element/s with the amp-script component:

```
<amp-script width="200" height="100" script="ticker">
     <span id="progressive_span">UPDATING</span>
</amp-script>
```

The JS file

```
<!-- Fetch remote js-->
<amp-script src="https://tickers.ABC.com/hello.js"></amp-script>

<!-- js-->    
<script id="ticker" type="text/plain" target="amp-script">
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (event) {
        var ticker = new Ticker({ info: 2 });
        ticker.attachToTextBox('progressive_span');
        ticker.SetCurrencySign('IDR ');
        ticker.tick();
    });
</script>
```

But it seems ticker function is not loaded.